# How can I get a random row from MySQL and have the data displayed on page?

Tags: python, mysql

I am working on a project that allows a user to get a random message from MySQL and have it displayed on a page.
I am creating the query to grab a random row within MySQL using `SELECT * FROM messages ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1` and have tested it within MySQL and it works. My next step is to have the randomly selected row displayed on the page.

My model is

```
@classmethod
def random_message(cls):
    query = "SELECT * FROM messages ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1"
    results =  connectToMySQL("messages_db").query_db(query)
    if results:
        temp_message = cls(results[0])
        return temp_message
```

Followed by my controller to display my randomly selected row.

```
@app.route("/message")
def my_message():
    messages = Message.random_message()
    return render_template('message.html', messages=messages)
```

On my webpage, when I select the button I have set up to go to "/message", I run into a new error. The error I get when I attempt to go to the next page is `TypeError: 'Message' object is not iterable` . Per Pauls comment, I had removed "data" from `def random_message(cls, data)` and had to remove it from the results line after `.query_db(query, data)`.

This is how I am attempting to grab the info

```
{% for message in messages %}
<p>{{message.message}}</p>
<p>{{message.creator}}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

And this is how my table is set up
[image]

Comment: delete data from def random_message and try again

Comment: That's an expensive query to run. Don't run it too often if the table is large.

Comment: @PaulCollingwood I updated my question with the changes you suggested, I go through to the next webpage with no error, but nothing is being displayed..

Comment: @TheImpaler I saw that there was a way by doing it with importing random, but I was not sure how to write out the code and saw that by running the query it was a bit more simple so thats why I went with that

Comment: `random_message` is returning `None`as it might not be entering in the `if` block. Where does `connectToMySQL` come from?

Comment: @JMA i updated my question with a current error I am receiving. The connectToMySQL is coming from a configuration file i have set up that connects me to MySQL

Comment: in function you use `results[0]` - so you get single element. But in template you use `{% for message in messages %}` so you expect list with many elements. You have to decide what you really want to use. If you want to use `for`-loop then you should send `messages=[messages]` instead of `messages=messages`. You have missleading names of variables - your function has name `random_message()` which means it gives single element but you assign to variable `messages = ...` which suggests that you have many elements (in list, dictionary or tuple)

Comment: @furas yes thanks you! i ended up changing it to `cls(row)`  and appending it to an empty list

Answer (score 0):

The `messages` object that you are generating with the `random_message` method is probably returning `None` as it might not be entering the `if` block. Therefore, when you are trying to iterate over this object with `{% for message in messages %}`, you are getting the error: `'Message' object is not iterable`.

The issue seems to be with the connection to MySQL.